# Is it possible to use diatomic carbon to utilize a new type of fuel that takes away the waste product of carbon dioxide being released into the air?

Tags: gas-laws

These days, we as a community what to polish and make our world a greener environment. I found a way to accomplish this task, however I don't know if it is applicable. I am wondering if the use of diatonic carbon would do the trick to produce a process that could regenerate the fuel in our vehicles and eliminate the releasing of carbon dioxide into the air. The purpose of this reaction would be to remove the Carbon Dioxide waste that is created by gasoline. Gasoline waste contains one less carbon than was originally in the reaction

**(UNDER CONSTRUCTION)**

Comment: Welcome to ChemistrySE! I think in the body of your question you should explain your question  title (not very clear in my opinion :-) not global warming!

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate the outcome of a reaction between C2 and carbon dioxide?

Comment: Wow - on several levels. No. First Law of Thermodynamics: You cannot win. Second Law of Thermodynamics: You can only break even on a very cold day. Third Law of Thermodynamics: It never gets that cold.

Comment: The answer rests on what diatomic carbon is. I have no idea what it is. But, if such a thing could exist, the issue would be: does it require more energy to create than any other way of absorbing or reacting carbon dioxide? Unless diatomic carbon were a free resource, it seems unlikely there would be any net environmental gain.

Answer (score 1):

No doubt, diatomic carbon does exist - in blue flames and in comets.

The characteristic uv absorption pattern (*Swan* bands) has already been described almost 100 years ago.

At low temperature (77 K) it reacts with hydrocarbons by H-abstraction to form $\ce{HC#CH}$, and the addition to $\ce{C=C}$ double bonds has been reported too.

But I can't figure out any reasonable way for a reaction with carbon dioxide.